# How to identify port number of a desktop application(Windows and MAC) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a desktop application that is running on a particular port in a Windows machine. I am now developing a chrome extension that interacts with the desktop application. I would like to know the port number on which the desktop application is running.

Is there any way how I can identify the port number of an application using javascript ? Any pointers will be really helpful.

Comment: There is no way for us to know if the application has some method built in for you to do that. Particularly, given that you haven't told us what application. Are you asking if there is some generic way for you, from extension JavaScript, to have the browser scan all applications on the machine and see what networking ports they are using? If that's your question, then "No".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`chrome.sockets.tcp`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp) to connect to a known endpoint.

You have to request the [specific endpoint in the manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network) in order to have permission to access it.

If the manifest allows it you could try lots of ports at that endpoint until you found one that responded with your service, but that would be **sloooooooooow** and incredibly bug prone.

Instead choose a specific port (or make it configurable) and just connect directly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I guess most of the extensions now work in that fashion. However, I am thinking of a scenario where an attacker runs a malware server at a specific port (that is dedicated to the application which will communicate with the extension). In that case, the extension will not be able to communicate with the respective desktop application. On the other hand, say if the malware server responds to the extension's requests in the correct manner, how will the extension get to know that it is communicating with the exact right application.

Comment: @Viman sounds like you need a cryptographic signature of some kind, a public key that your expected app has the matching private key to, but that the malware doesn't have. If the service at the expected port can't respond securely you should throw an error and warn the user, not scan for alternate ports.